# access data inside each helper in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember route with a model hook that returns a jquery promise; the data is returned correctly and its structure is:

```
{
    status: 'success',
    data: [...]
}
```

In the template I'm trying to access the data field (is an array of objects, each of them with username and other properties).

```
{{#each model.data in data}}
    - this is a user:
    {{???.username}}
{{/each}}
```

I can't understand what I have to use instead of "???" to be able to display the username; I can see that the data is cycled correctly by the each helper because I get the string "- this is a user:" as many times as the data array's length

Comment: Which version of ember are you using? See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using the latest stable ( 2.2 if I remember right).. I'll try the block param, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [block parameter](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params) syntax which looks like the following:

```
{{#each model.data as |item|}}
     {{item.username}}
{{/each}}
```